# How to use mockito to create mock api response in android

Tags: android, mockito

I am trying to create a mock response of an api call in an Android app.
Is Mockito the best way to go for that? I wanted to create a mock json of the actual api call
so that it I can test my app behaviour for different responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're really interested in mocking actual HTTP responses (response body, status codes, etc.), you should take a look at [MockWebServer](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver).

But in most cases, it makes more sense to use Mockito or Mockk (if you're using Kotlin) to mock responses from your local data sources like Repositories or Use Cases. So consider this approach if you have at least minimal wrapping logic around low-level networking stuff like OkHttp / Retrofit.

Comment: Thanks @fraggjkee. WIth Mockito can I still use a mock JSON or I have to create a Mock
response object instead?

Comment: Use MockWebServer if you want to mock JSON. Mockito is for mocking POJOs which are created from JSON response.

Comment: in case we are using retrofit and let's say we created POJO objects using Mockito. Then how can we still test the app architecture, since the response callbacks of the api are tied to the Retrofit(and they are immutable)

Comment: it's hard to answer without seeing your code. if you use plain `Call` from retrofit then it may more sense to use MockWebServer. But you should still be able to mock Call responses from your retrofit interfaces by creating them manually in initializing with manually created POJOs.

Comment: Yeah. Actually I found that its better to use MockWebServer and use the Call that way.
Thanks!!